# Recursive function references in OCaml?

Tags: function, reference, ocaml, sml

Today we learned about "tying the knot" in SML where you have something like this

```
val tempFunc = ref (fn k:int => true);
fun even x = if x = 0 then true else !tempFunc(x-1);
fun odd x = if x = 0 then false else even(x-1);
tempFunc := odd;
```

and i'm working with ocaml which is ridiculously similar, but i'm just having trouble kind of doing the same thing. The thing I found that is the closest is

```
let tempFunc {contents =x}=x;;
```

but i don't really understand that, and how i could tie that tempFunc to another function. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The direct translation of your code in OCaml is:

```
let tempFunc = ref (fun k -> true)
let even x = if x = 0 then true else !tempFunc (x-1)
let odd x = if x = 0 then false else even (x-1)
let () = tempFunc := odd
```

The idiomatic way to do this (as it is in SML as well) is to use recursive functions:

```
let rec even x = if x = 0 then true  else odd  (x-1)
and     odd  x = if x = 0 then false else even (x-1)
```

Comment: (Using `and` would be idiomatic in SML also.  This is just an example to show the idea of tying the knot.)

Comment: wow, i feel like i tried that before and got errors but i must have just missed something, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent OCaml code is

```
let tempFunc = ref (fun (k: int) -> true);;

let even x = if x = 0 then true else !tempFunc (x-1);;

let odd x = if x = 0 then false else even (x-1);;

tempFunc := odd;;
```

As you say, it's virtually identical to the SML code.

(Edited to add: actually, Thomas's code is a little bit prettier!)

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to have the same thing without using references:

```
let rec even_helper f x = if x = 0 then true else f even_helper (x-1);;
let rec odd_helper f x = if x = 0 then false else f odd_helper (x-1);;
let even = even_helper odd_helper;;
let odd = odd_helper even_helper;;
```

Note that this code involves unguarded recursive types: the type of a helper is `('a -> int -> bool) -> int -> bool as 'a`, meaning that the first argument to a helper is a function whose first argument is a helper. Such types are accepted by Ocaml, but only if you pass the `-rectypes` option to the compiler.

Using more functions you can do away with the `rec` altogether. This is not a direct answer to your question, but rather a side-track showing how that pattern would look in a purely functional way.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Yes, it does, but you need `-rectypes`.

Comment: @gilles: I knew I was missing something... I'll edit this later with one of the usual workarounds for recursive types...